# In Cocos2d, if ccp is to make a CGPoint, is there a macro or function to make a CGSize?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

In Cocos2d for iPhone/iPad, if `ccp` is to make a `CGPoint`, is there a macro or function to make a `CGSize`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here you go

```
#define ccs(__W__, __H__) CGSizeMake(__W__, __H__)
```

Answer (score 1):

No but you can easily make your own macro to do this. In fact if you look at the cocos code that creates `ccp` you will see it is really quite basic. Open up the ccmacros file and take a look at it.

Comment: aha, yes, i just wonder why there isn't a standard made to do that

Answer (score 0):

I think this works:

```
CGSizeMake
```

Comment: Ah sorry, didn't realize. I just never found much difference.